# How to extract row of elements from a string that has the structure of a table/dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm facing a problem that I'm hoping to find a general solution.

I'm trying to find the hard drive serial numbers (with it's corresponding name) with python via terminal with the following:

```
command = "lsblk --nodeps -o name,serial"
process = os.popen(command)
terminal_output = str(process.read())[:-1]
```

Printing out `terminal_output` this gets me something like below:

```
NAME    SERIAL
loop0   
loop1   
loop2   
loop3   
loop4   
nvme0n1 BTTE00141CWK512B-1
nvme1n1 BTTE00141CWK512B-2
```

The problem is that the output is a `string`. Is there a way that I can convert this to a table? Ie, pandas dataframe or any other general method that can extract the serial number with it's corresponding name?

My initial attempt is to split the string at spaces so it becomes:

```
['NAME', 'SERIAL', 'loop0', 'loop1', 'loop2', 'loop3', 'loop4', 'nvme0n1', 'BTTE00141CWK512B-1', 'nvme1n1', 'BTTE00141CWK512B-2']
```

Problem is that I still can't group them into twos because `loop0` to `loop4` don't have serial numbers. (There could also be cases where there is a `loop5` between the two harddrives.) What I am hoping to get is something like below:

```
nvme0n1 BTTE00141CWK512B-1
nvme1n1 BTTE00141CWK512B-2
```

But really as long as I can find `all serial numbers with their corresponding names` any format is ok.

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: Just the corresponding name and serial number. If it's in a dataframe then great, but as long as I can find all the ```names``` and their respective ```serial numbers```, like what's in the last code block above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply feed the output string into `pd.read_csv()` as `io.StringIO`. Set the separator as one or more spaces so the columns can be read correctly. Setting `NAME` and `SERIAL` in the header is optional.

```
import io
import pandas as pd

terminal_output = """NAME    SERIAL
loop0   
loop1   
loop2   
loop3   
loop4   
nvme0n1 BTTE00141CWK512B-1
nvme1n1 BTTE00141CWK512B-2"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(terminal_output), sep=r"\s+", header=0)
```

Output

```
print(df)
      NAME              SERIAL
0    loop0                 NaN
1    loop1                 NaN
2    loop2                 NaN
3    loop3                 NaN
4    loop4                 NaN
5  nvme0n1  BTTE00141CWK512B-1
6  nvme1n1  BTTE00141CWK512B-2
```

Answer (score 2):

If your output looks like in the question, you can use `pandas.read_fwf` to parse it to dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


s = '''NAME    SERIAL
loop0   
loop1   
loop2   
loop3   
loop4   
nvme0n1 BTTE00141CWK512B-1
nvme1n1 BTTE00141CWK512B-2'''

df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(s))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      NAME              SERIAL
0    loop0                 NaN
1    loop1                 NaN
2    loop2                 NaN
3    loop3                 NaN
4    loop4                 NaN
5  nvme0n1  BTTE00141CWK512B-1
6  nvme1n1  BTTE00141CWK512B-2
```